# Mark the current configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, configuration-managment

I want to have visual evidence of my current configuration in Visual Studio.

To be more clear... if I use SMSS, I can specify a custom color for each connection

[image]

is it possible to do the same in Visual Studio, if I choose a configuration from here?

[image]